# GitHub Actions self-hosted runner shuts down with a strange error

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Randomly my GitHub runner shuts down with the following error:

> The self-hosted runner: default-6bbn8-hw2mr lost communication with the server. Verify the machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything in your workflow that terminates the runner process, starves it for CPU/Memory, or blocks its network access can cause this error.

The running code definitely has lower resources than the runner can offer!

Couldn't fins anything helpful online. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Must not be resource constraints, as the diagnostic message suggests, the runner process might just have been stopped, the network has been stopped or the whole machine has been stopped. What have you tried to find the actual case? Was the network connection healthy at the time of the diagnostic?

Comment: @hakre network connection was healthy and the runner has enough resources. This error comes very randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by CPU/memory being full. You can clear the cache before running. Here's an example with Node.js:

```
name: Node.js CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Clean npm cache
        run: npm cache clean --force
      - run: npm ci
      # - run: npm run build --if-present
      # - run: npm test
```